# Should I capitalize "amazons" when I am talking about the Greek female warriors?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I am doing an essay about the amazons from *A Midsummer Night's Dream* and I don't know if the word "amazons" should be capitalized.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We appreciate questions that show some research before posting, and those that are answerable in general reference are considered off-topic. If you require assistance in framing a question, please visit our [Help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) “How to write a good question”.

Comment: Thank you and I am new to this so that is a lot of help for me and I looked it up but for a while all I was getting was the rain forest.

Comment: Type in "amazon women". Amazons will get you the forest.

Comment: Okay thanks you are helping a lot and if you could give me some pointers about how to use this I will also appreciate it

Comment: Is there anything else I should know about this website since i just found it about 19 minutes ago

Comment: Thank you you have been very helpful and is there any way of "following" you for all your help or any way to help you with anything?

Comment: Also, how do You get a score on something?

Comment: By something I mean a question.

Comment: How do you get reputation? I am sorry about all these questions and I read all the help things but your answers are more helpful than the given ones.

Comment: Could you help me so I don't have this long thing in my comments section I had something pop up saying not to have a long comment area.

Comment: Okay thanks is there anything major I should know...sorry I left for dinner.

Comment: What is Meta for I just unlocked it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54912/discussion-between-zoe-and-sumelic).